# Does $\Vert f\Vert_{L^\infty}^2\leq \Vert f\Vert_{L^2}\Vert f'\Vert_{L^2}$ hold?

Tags: measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I know that Sobolev's embedding implies that $H^1(\mathbb{R})\hookrightarrow C(\mathbb{R})\cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, which in particular implies that $$
\Vert f\Vert_{L^\infty}\leq \Vert f\Vert_{H^1}.
$$
Now, I was wondering about the following slightly more specific (?) inequality. More precisely, I was wondering if $f\in H^1(\mathbb{R})$, then the following inequality holds:
$$
\Vert f\Vert_{L^\infty}^2\leq \Vert f\Vert_{L^2}\Vert f'\Vert_{L^2}.
$$
The problem here is to be able to put a factor only with the $L^2$ norm of $f$. Does this inequality hold?

Comment: Isn't that essentially the Sobolev embedding for $f^2$, plus Cauchy-Schwarz?

Comment: @D.Thomine Is it? I do not see how could you get the $L^2$ norm of $f$ on the right-hand side. Could you elaborate a little bit more pls?

Comment: Sorry, that's a bit tougher than I thought. My idea works well for $H_0^1 (\mathbb{T})$ -- i.e. functions in Sobolev space on the circle with average $0$ -- but on $\mathbb{R}$ some care is needed because of low frequencies. On the other hand, this inequality scales well, so it doesn't seem that low frequencies should matter.

Comment: That's simpler than I though. Instead of the Sobolev embedding, start from $\|f\|_{\mathbb{L}^\infty} \leq \frac{1}{2} \|f'\|_{\mathbb{L}^1}$. Apply to $f^2$, use Cauchy-Schwarz, density argument, end.

Comment: Note that this is the [Agmon inequality](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277884/proof-of-agmons-inequality-in-mathbbr3) in 1D.

Comment: @Fritz I don't understand, the inequality you are referring to depends on the $H^2$ norm of the function, while my question only requires $H^1$ regularity. They don't look related to me.

Comment: @Neldrock See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agmon%27s_inequality) for the general case in bounded domains, see the last inequality in $n$-dimensional domains. The one on MO is how to adapt to the unbounded case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f \in \mathcal{S} (\mathbb{R})$. Let $x^*$ be any point realizing the maximum of $|f|$. Then

$$2|f(x^*)| = \left|\int_{-\infty}^{x^*} f'(t) \ dt\right| + \left|\int_{x^*}^{+\infty} f'(t) \ dt\right| \leq \|f'\|_{\mathbb{L}^1}.$$

Hence, $\|f\|_{\mathbb{L}^\infty} \leq \frac{1}{2} \|f'\|_{\mathbb{L}^1}$. Applying this inequality to $f^2$ and using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,

$$\|f\|_{\mathbb{L}^\infty}^2 = \|f^2\|_{\mathbb{L}^\infty} \leq \frac{1}{2} \|(f^2)'\|_{\mathbb{L}^1} = \|ff'\|_{\mathbb{L}^1} \leq \|f\|_{\mathbb{L}^2} \|f'\|_{\mathbb{L}^2}.$$

Finally, $\mathcal{S} (\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $H^1 (\mathbb{R})$, and all of $f \mapsto \|f\|_{\mathbb{L}^\infty}$, $f \mapsto \|f\|_{\mathbb{L}^2}$ and $f \mapsto \|f'\|_{\mathbb{L}^2}$ are continuous in the $H^1$ norm (the later two by definition of the $H^1$ norm, the former by the Sobolev embedding). Hence the claimed inequality actually holds in $H^1 (\mathbb{R})$.